# Get data from a non-uniform list

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a list like: `list={{a},{b,c},{d,e}}`, I want `{c,e}`.
How can I get the second part of every element in a list?
I have tried `list[[All,2]]`. It doesn't work since there is only one part`{a}` in the first element of the list. I know `list[[2;;3,2]]` would work, but I have a very large list and I don't know which one has two parts.

Comment: Since no one else suggested it, `In[177]:= Map[
 Extract[PadRight[#, 2, Hold[Nothing]], 2, Release] &, list]

Out[177]= {c, e}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that the last element of the 2-element sublists is required, let's consider the lists (one borrowed from @bmf/OP each):

```
alist = {{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}}
blist = {{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f, g, h}, {k}, {l, m, n}, {o, p}}

Cases[#, {a_, b_} -> b] & /@ {alist, blist}
```

> `{{c, e}, {c, e, p}}`

---

To extend to the case where sublists can have two or more elements, the second element can be extracted as follows:

```
Cases[#, {a_, b_, c___} :> b] & /@ {alist, blist}
```

> `{{c, e}, {c, e, g, m, p}}`

---

One could `PadRight` (in this case) prior to extracting the second column. `x` could be any element that is not present in the list.

```
#[[All, 2]] & /@ (PadRight[#, Automatic, x] & /@ {alist, blist}) /. 
 x -> Nothing
```

> `{{c, e}, {c, e, g, m, p}}`

Comment: Very nice!! And I think we have 5 so far

Comment: Very nice, Indeed!

Comment: Hi @Syed! Thanks for always sharing with great respect.

Answer (score 7):

I am giving a general answer, in the sense that it should work for any non-uniform list of sub-lists.

Consider this list

```
list = {{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f, g, h}, {k}, {l, m, n}, {o, p}}
```

We want to extract `{c,e,p}`

Select the sublists that are of the form you want

```
sorted = Select[list, (Length[#] == 2) &]
```

> [image: sorted]

Get the elements you want

```
sorted[[1 ;; Length@sorted, 2]]
```

> [image: res]

And as a one-liner

```
Select[list, (Length[#] == 2) &][[1 ;; 
   Length@(Select[list, (Length[#] == 2) &]), 2]]
```

Comment: Hi~ I didn't get enough reputation to upvote your answer before this question. It's a late upvote. Your answer really helped me. Thanks~

Comment: @ddwell thanks. glad I was able to help :-)

Answer (score 7):

Another option. Use a simple `If` statement to check the length. This assumes all elements are one dimensional lists.

```
list = {{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}}
Map[If[Length[#] >= 2, #[[2]], Nothing] &, list]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the check is only for sublists of length 2 and no more than two, then the above becomes

```
list = {{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f, g, h}, {k}, {l, m, n}, {o, p}}    
Map[If[Length[#] == 2, Last[#], Nothing] &, list]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It's a very nice answer and it's a (+1) but in the OP it is mentioned that we don't know exactly how many sublists have two elements. For a list of the form `{{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f, g, h}, {k}, {l, m, n}, {o, p}}` it gives the wrong result, but I think you should be able to modify appropriately :-)

Comment: @bmf could you please clarify why it gives wrong answer? I get `{c, e, g, m, p}` as answer for the input `list = {{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f, g, h}, {k}, {l, m, n}, {o, p}}`. Isn't this correct?

Comment: Because if I understand correctly the OP we want the second element of those sublists that contain exactly two elements. Maybe I am wrong though

Comment: The hint in the OP -as I understand it- is the part `, but I have a very large list and I don't know which one has two parts`

Comment: @bmf, I see. In that case, will adjust my `If`, no problem. thanks.

Comment: Hi @Nasser! Thanks for always sharing and being an example for this community.

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to use Flatten:

```
Flatten[list, {{2}, {1}}]
```

`{{a, b, d}, {c, e}}`

So,

```
Flatten[list, {{2}, {1}}][[2]]
```

`{c, e}`

Comment: It's a very nice answer and it's a (+1) but in the OP it is mentioned that we don't know exactly how many sublists have two elements. For a list of the form `{{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f, g, h}, {k}, {l, m, n}, {o, p}}` it gives the wrong result, but I think you should be able to modify appropriately :-)

Comment: Please explain. For `list = {{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f, g, h}, {k}, {l, m, n}, {o, p}}`, `Flatten[list, {{2}, {1}}][[2]]` gives `{c, e, g, m, p}`. Is that not what would be desired?

Comment: Because if I understand correctly the OP we want the second element of those sublists that contain exactly two elements. Maybe I am wrong though

Comment: The hint in the OP -as I understand it- is the part `, but I have a very large list and I don't know which one has two parts`

Comment: I suppose that could be the case, but all I see is "the second part of every element in a list", and I think I've provided a solution that does that without making any further assumptions.

Comment: I never meant to offend or anything like that. Of course your solution works nicely for this case, I just thought to add a comment :-)

Comment: I'm not offended, it just seems weird to duplicate the comment for everyone's answer rather than pose the question directly to the OP.

Comment: Each answer is different by a different person. I thought to, at least, have the courtesy to inform each person how, in my opinion, they could provide a more thorough answer. That's all

Comment: I've learned a lot of sharing with you two in this community, and it's a shame I can't share a beer or wine to wish you a happy new year in a few hours. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 5):

Sow and Reap do the trick.

```
{{a},{b,c},{d,e}} //
Map[  If[  Length@# >=2, Sow @ #[[2]]  ]&  ]//
Reap //
Last //
First
```

> {c, e}

Answer (score 5):

Interpreting the question as @bmf has done, that is what the OP requires is the second element of all 2-element sublists:

**Pick**

```
list = {{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}}

Pick[#,Length/@#,2]&[list][[All,2]]

(* {c, e} *)
```

Also, for `blist`:

```
blist = {{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f, g, h}, {k}, {l, m, n}, {o, p}}

Pick[#,Length/@#,2]&[blist][[All,2]]

(* {c, e, p} *)
```

**Reap and Sow**

`Reap` and `Sow` may also be used as follows (slightly different from the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277998/106) given below by @AsukaMinato):

```
Reap[Sow[#,Length@#==2]&/@blist,True][[2,1,All,2]]

(* {c, e, p} *)
```

To get list containing all non {x,y} sub-lists from `blist`:

```
Reap[Sow[#,Length@#==2]&/@blist,False][[2,1]]

(* {{a}, {f, g, h}, {k}, {l, m, n}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Join @@ (If[Length[#] == 2, Take[#, {2}], Nothing] & /@ list)
(*edit suggested by @bmf*)
(*{c, e}*)
```

Comment: It's a very nice answer and it's a (+1) but in the OP it is mentioned that we don't know exactly how many sublists have two elements. For a list of the form `{{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f, g, h}, {k}, {l, m, n}, {o, p}}` it gives the wrong result, but I think you should be able to modify appropriately :-)

Comment: Hi, friend! Thanks for the observation. I'll fix it in a moment :-)